# how to compile text present in a cell ? (excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

in a cell there is this text: Sum(d5:d10), please notice there is no "=". I want to use this text in another cell with "=" and have the result of the calculation of the sum of the range  d5:d10, the return i want is not the text.

My purpose is not to calculate the sum, but i want to use the text of a cell in another cell begining with "=" and have the results of the calculations. ie: how to compile text in excel.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/430480/excel-define-a-formula-in-one-cell-to-be-used-in-other-cells-with-different-in

Comment: @Doomenik Merci!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the text "SUM(A1:B1)" in cell C1, and you want the result of this in D1

1. Go to Formulas Define Name
2. Choose a name (eg Answer)
3. In the Refers to box, type =EVALUATE(C1)
4. Click OK
5. In Cell D1, type = Answer

[image: Result]

Comment: I can't find Evaluate as a worksheet function.  Must be a throwback to Excel 4 macro language.   http://www.ozgrid.com/News/excel-evaluate-formula-VBA.htm

Comment: It&#39;s &#39;old magic&#39; ie it works but is undocumented. It is not a worksheet function which is why you have to do it this strange way.

Comment: This knowledge deserves to be preserved.

Comment: It makes an #name? for me, any help ?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: To be honest I did not check this answer :) , now I have it is not working as expected.  Changing A1 did not update immediately.  =Answer only got updated once I pressed F2 and re-enter on my formula.  I've changed my function to have Application.Volatile and now my function and =Answer update in real time.   So it looks like it needs a nudge to recalculate.

Comment: 2016 pack office

Comment: It works for me with Evaluate(Indirecte(D2)), and D2 contains D1, :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, define a function that evalulates internally.  Call it from worksheet with something like `=MetaFunction("sum(E4:E6)")` .  This worked for me.  I populated cells `E4:E6` with 1,2,3 and got 6.

Alternatively put `"=MetaFunction(G3)"` and then in G3 the formula is `="Sum(E4:E6)"` (this is more line with your use case).  Still worked for me, 6.

Very curious about why you'd need this, an extra layer of "meta" must make this worksheet slow.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MetaFunction(ByVal sFormula As String)
    Application.Volatile
    MetaFunction = Application.Evaluate(sFormula)
End Function
```